# Get the last SP/Query who activated "BEGIN TRANSACTION"

Tags: sql-server

I just want to know if it is possible in SQL Server 2008 to know the last SP/query that generated the "begin transaction"

Thank you so much for your response

Answer (score 0):

Information about active transaction DBCC OPENTRAN

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-opentran-transact-sql

Variant B

```
CREATE TABLE #OpenTranStatus (  
   ActiveTransaction varchar(25),  
   Details sql_variant   
   );  
-- Execute the command, putting the results in the table.  
INSERT INTO #OpenTranStatus   
   EXEC ('DBCC OPENTRAN WITH TABLERESULTS, NO_INFOMSGS');  

-- Display the results.  
SELECT * FROM #OpenTranStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

- Transactions are specific to sessions, so there could be many concurrent ones
- Transactions can be implicit and any standalone UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE will be a self contained transactions

Now that's out of the way, you have DMVs like [sys.dm_tran_active_transactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-active-transactions-transact-sql) and [others](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/transaction-related-dynamic-management-views-and-functions-transact-sql) which give you everything.

It depends what you actually need of course.

There is no transaction history though, so once committed/rolled back you have no trace.